# Consumir API Rest em C# por Ajax em jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, rest, asp.net-web-api

**Ola**
Tenho uma API em C# que Me Retorna um objeto em JSON Segue o código

```
[HttpGet]
        public string Login(string Pass, string User)
        {
            Return ret = new Return();
            try
            {
                UsuarioDAL DAL = new UsuarioDAL();
                var Usuario = DAL.ValidarLogin(Pass, User);

                if (Usuario.CPF != null)
                {
                    ret.OK = true;
                    ret.obj = Usuario;
                }
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ret);

            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ret);
            }
        }
    }
```

Fiz uma chamada em JQUERY usando AJAX para este método

```
    var Login = function (Fn) {
  switch(Fn){
      case 'logar':
          var USER = $('#Name').val();
          var PASS = $('#Pass').val();
          ValidLogin(USER,PASS);
  }
};


function ValidLogin(Us,Ps){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:49982/api/values/Login?Pass=' + Ps + '&User=' + Us + '',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Acesso').click(function () {
        Login('logar');
    });
});
```

**Fiz o debug e a url realmente chama a API retorna o Dado em JSON
só que o jquery me retorna o erro
ReferenceError do objeto data que coloquei para exibir no console**

Comment: dataType: 'xml' e no servidor retorna em json, o correto seria dataType: 'json'

Comment: há sim. é esqueci de mudar essa parte, estava testando em xml, mas o erro persiste, desconsidere o xml.